# Logging each in/out of each function

Tags: python

Currently I typically add a log line to my functions with details of the variables that are inputted and returned. However I am looking for an elegant way around this.

Is there a way to log each input to a function and what is returned using some form of magic methods?

Below is an example,

```
class exampleclass(object):
    def __init__(self,size=False):
        self.size = size

    def funt1(self,weight=None):
        return weight

    def funt2(self,shape=None):
        return shape
```

Here I want to log the returned variable and also what is inputted for each function using the smallest amount of code possible.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html) to "debug" your code and trace all function calls. If you don't want to do that, then you probably want to use a metaclass to avoid decorating every method.

Comment: @felix001 Did my answer solved your query?

Comment: It did, but Im wondering if anyone has any other solutions that would not involve decorators on each function. But instead a single method call within each class.

Comment: @Bakuriu can you help me understand how to use meta classes in this example?

Comment: Calling decorators is single line, I think.

Comment: But what would the code look like

Comment: I've mentioned it in my answer. Look at it below. You just have to add `@log` above each method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a concept of [decorators in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators). They help you abstract out the common code you want to inject on any function on your will. Make a decorator named `log` as follows:

```
import logging
from functools import wraps

def log(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            logging.debug("args - %s", str(args))
            logging.debug("kwargs - %s", str(kwargs))
            response = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            logging.debug("response - %s", str(response))
            return response
    return wrapper
```

Now, you can use this decorator for any function as follows:

```
@log
def funt1(self,weight=None):
    return weight
```

The above code will log all the arguments & their returned values with just 1 line of code.

[Here](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) is a good blog on understanding decorators.

Comment: Would be better to use `logging.debug("args - %s", args)` etc